# Calling ReactDOM.render() function instead of using stateful components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been learning react for past 2 Days in [FullstackOpen](https://fullstackopen.com/en/part1/component_state_event_handlers#stateful-component). When they intent to introduce `Stateful component` they mentioned the below line

> Making repeated calls to the `ReactDOM.render` method is not the
> recommended way to re-render components. Next, we'll introduce a
> better way of accomplishing this effect.

So why repeated calls to the `ReactDOM.render` method is not recommended ?

Thank You

Comment: `ReactDOM.render()` repeatedly called can be fine in certain situations.  But I think they want to "think in React", which means, for ReactJS coders, think of a way of modifying the state that produces the desired result for the user.  So, repeated `setState()` calls instead.

Comment: If you manually re-run ReactDOM.render() you don't get the benefits of the virtual DOM. You just want to run it once per app.

Comment: @loremdipso Thank You and What do you mean my benefits of the virtual DOM ?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html. tl;dr - performance is better with the virtual DOM than the normal one. React makes a bunch of virtual DOMs because it's cheap, only touching the real DOM to apply changes from the virtual DOM.

Comment: Thank you @loremdipso. And to be more clear. ReactDOM.render interacts with the Real DOM whereas state components interacts with Virtual DOM. Correct me if I am wrong.